# Changing locale setting doesn't apply in PyGObject under Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, locale, gtk3, pygobject

I'm migrating a Python app from Python 2.7 to 3.9 which used PyGTK. It now uses PyGObject under Anaconda since I want to distribute an easily installable environment to run the source code, and MSYS2 didn't have all the necesary libraries. I have an environment with gtk3 and pygobject packages installed from conda-forge channel.

Thing is, I want the application to be fully in Spanish, but the auto-generated text in some buttons like the FileChooserButton and some menus like FileChooserDialog come in English. I've tried generating such widgets in MSYS2 and they appear in Spanish without doing anything, so I deduced that the problem comes from Anaconda.

I've tried setting the LANG environment variable to 'es_ES' and calling `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'')` at the beginning, but nothing changes. When I call `locale.getdefaultlocale()` it returns `('es_ES', 'cp1252')`, so I don't know why it doesn't pick that one.

Is there a conda package I have to install so that Python uses my locale like MSYS2 does? Is there a conda configuration I must change?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm on Windows 10.